# Is there an existing object oriented database native to PHP like for example db4o in C# and Java?

Tags: php, web-applications, object-oriented-database

Incase you dont want to use relational database...

Comment: why does this get downvoted? (apart from being maybe poorly phrased)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, CouchDB isn't native to PHP, but it's native to the web.  It stores data in JSON format, which can be directly converted to PHP objects.  You could try using that.

http://couchdb.apache.org/

If that doesn't help, look up "NoSQL".  It's a movement of using databases that aren't relational.

Comment: Thanks tjameson, I found Memcached, Redis and MongoDB aside from CouchDB in http://nosql-database.org/